# Calling Firebase Cloud Function from Angular 4 Component

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I´m working with Angular 4, Firebase Database and Cloud Functions. The question: How can I call a Firebase Function on click from my component?

Just what I try to do: Sending a test email with emailjs on button click.

My code:

**functions/src/index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const emailjs = require("emailjs/email");

export const sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  var email     = require("./path/to/emailjs/email");
  var server    = email.server.connect({
    user:    "username",
    password:"password",
    host:    "smtp.your-email.com",
    ssl:     true
  });

  // send the message and get a callback with an error or details of the message that was sent
  server.send({
    text:    "i hope this works",
    from:    "you <username@your-email.com>",
    to:      "someone <someone@your-email.com>, another <another@your-email.com>",
    cc:      "else <else@your-email.com>",
    subject: "testing emailjs"
  }, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
})
```

**My component**

```
sendTestEmail() {
  // From here I want to call the "sendMail" function from Firebase to send an email.
}
```

So: How can I call a Firebase Function from my component?

Answer (score 3):

You are using an **HTTP Cloud Function**, therefore you have to trigger it by calling a specific URL, as explained in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function

> After an HTTP function is deployed, you can invoke it through its own
>   unique URL. The URL includes the following, in order:
>
> ```
> - The region in which your function is deployed
> - Your Firebase project ID
> - cloudfunctions.net
> - The name of your function
> ```

So, in your case, the URL to invoke sendMail() is:

```
https://us-central1-<your-project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/sendMail
```

You should use the HttpClient service to trigger this call.

---

Finally, I would suggest you watch the following video from the Firebase team which details how HTTP Cloud Functions shall be written, and in particular how to send a response to the caller:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

You will probably see that you need to slightly adapt your code accordingly.